# Laravel is not attaching css, but it is existing

Tags: php, css, laravel, sass

I'm new in Laravel. I started new project with Jetstream, and all goes well excepting one thing: CSS file is empty so auth form is looking rawly.

I got *public/css/app.css* file with needed style code, but for some reason browser receives it as empty

In layout/app.blade.php is declared:
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ mix('css/app.css') }}">`

I tried to replace it by:
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}">`

But it is not working. Any ideas? Thank you

Comment: What url is created when you use `mix` ? Can you access that URL by hand ?

Comment: @matiaslauriti when I try to open this CSS by hand in browser, I get an empty file. If I delete the `public/css/app.css`, it returns 404, so laravel can see the file. And how can I know what url is created by `mix`? In terminal it shows no url

Comment: On the mix file in public folder

Comment: You say the file is empty. So, what makes you think Laravel is _failing_? Your file is empty. What have you done to fill it?

Comment: @matiaslauriti @Yinci it was my fail. I made  some manipulations with _.htaccess_ file to make my _index_ load from URL `site.com/`, not from `site.com/public`, so Laravel was distracted. Now I've fixed it and CSS is available by `asset('public/css/app.css')`. Thank you for your concern